# SF Duplicate Management: API Issues

Tags: api, form, duplicate-management

I'm working on setting up some new duplicate management rules, but just realized that the feature's interaction with API is inconvenient. We use FormAssembly to make forms that automatically create records in Salesforce. If we have a duplicate rule that shows an alert while creating a duplicate record, then anyone who fills out an online form can't submit it if there's a possible duplicate in Salesforce. Does anyone know how to make it so saving the form isn't blocked (outside of turning off the duplicate alerts)?

Comment: I'm curious on how you got it to work with the API.  That's the issue I'm having.  Reading the logs I see it checking for dupes, but doesn't reject any.  I think I'm not including the fields it matches over.